# When I disable buttons inside a div, they disappear

Tags: jquery

The problem is that, some users click more than once to send an alert. So, what I want is to add logic at the third like where it's said "Add logic here...". When the ajax call is made, I want all the button on that div to be disabled.

Here I have 2 buttons

```
<div id="reply_<%=item.AlertCategory %>_<%= item.Id %>">
  <input onclick="SaveReply(<%= item.Id %>, <%=item.AlertCategory %>, 
  <%=item.AlertType %>, <%= (int)AlertType.Email %>)" type="button" value="EMAIL"/>

  <input onclick="SaveReply(<%= item.Id %>, <%=item.AlertCategory %>, 
  <%=item.AlertType %>, <%= (int)AlertType.Post %>)" type="button" value="TEXT"/>
</div>
```

When clicked, they call they call **SaveReply** JavaScript function, the one below.

```
function SaveReply(id, category, alertType, saveAlertType) {
    if ($("#text_" + category + "_" + id).val() != "") {
        //Add logic here !!!!.....

        $.getJSON(getPath("Touch/TouchHome/SaveReply/" + id), {
            category: category,
            alertType: saveAlertType,
            text: $("#text_" + category + "_" + id).val(),
            random: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1024)
        },
            function(data) {
                $("#reply_" + category + "_" + id).hide();
                reloadDialog();
            }
        );
    }

}
```

This is what I'm using to disable those buttons (to be added at the 3rd line of the function)

```
var $btn = $("#reply_" + category + "_" + id).find(':button');
$btn.each(function () {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

But the problem is that when the buttons are disabled, they also disappear. I'm using **attr** instaed of **pop** because this application still uses jquery-1.4.1. version.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Use `$btn.attr('disabled', true)` for older jq versions...

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: or possibly even `this.disabled = true` so that it's ready to be upgraded to a newer jquery version later.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $btn = $("#reply_" + category + "_" + id).find(':button');
$btn.attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: I've tried the above, but buttons keeps disappearing after I disabled them. And the space they were occupying is not there anymore. So I can't even say that maybe the change color that why they not visible anymore. They are just gone. It's really strange. Maybe there is a hidden cause behind that.